# Two-way ANOVA (2x2) interpretation for non-significant values

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, interpretation, two-way

I'm a statistics beginner and for my research, I'm looking into the effect participants' body image (positive/negative) and an advert model type (thin/plus-sized) have on participants' view of their body image. So it's a 2x2 factorial ANOVA with the dependent variable being their body image difference recorded before and after viewing the model.

My Hypotheses are:

- If the consumer has a positive body image, using plus-sized models compared to thin-ideal models will have no effect on own body image
- If the consumer has a negative body image, using plus-sized models compared to thin-ideal models will improve their own body image

I've run the ANOVA and have got the following outcomes:
[image]

However, I'm struggling to understand how to interpret the data in relation to my hypothesis. I can't use the pairwise comparison as there aren't 3 categories. Do I need to use the estimated marginal means univariate tests to work out the significance of each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a two-way ANOVA, there are three possible hypotheses that can be tested: one for each of the two main effects and one for the interaction. Mapping these on to your example, the ANOVA can test the following hypotheses:

1. BodyImageGroup has an effect on time 1 to time 2 change (i.e., the mean change, your dependent variable, will differ between the two groups, positive and negative body image).
2. ModelType has an effect on time 1 to time 2 change (i.e., the mean change will differ between the two groups defined by the ModelType factor).
3. The effect of BodyImageGroup on change will dependent on ModelType. Or, stated the other way around, the effect of ModelType will depend on BodyImageGroup. In your example, the latter is more likely to make intuitive sense (the math doesn't care). Because this is a 2 by 2, this simplifies to saying that the effect of ModelType will differ between the positive and negative body image groups.

Notice that neither of your hypotheses aligns with what is being tested by the ANOVA model. This is likely why you are struggling to make sense of the results -- you are expecting something they are not showing. However, I can infer from what you've written that you think that the negative body image group will change as a result of ModelType but that the positive body image group will not. Thus, if you combine these two hypotheses into one hypothesis, you have an interaction. However, we cannot test whether one of the groups doesn't change (that would be trying to prove the null, a no-no in statistics). What we can test, and what the F for the interaction above tests, is whether the effect of ModelType differs between the positive-negative body image groups. Notice that this could take many forms: both change in the same direction but one changes more than the other; one changes but the other one does not, or they change in different directions.

In terms of your results, they do not support this hypothesis. The evidence failed to find an interaction effect. It did find statistically significant main effects for both factors, but based on what you've written, that was not of primary interest to this study. Bummer.

In terms of interpretation, you should focus on descriptive statistics, such as the mean change. I would actually recommend looking at all 6 means (time by model type by body image). Don't forget to report the standard deviations! Otherwise, it is difficult to have a sense of whether a difference in means is small or large.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Much appreciated! I've modified my hypotheses accordingly to the following: "There is a difference in participants body image change for different model types and participants body image groups"

In terms of looking at all 6 means, do you mean not using the difference and using the exact before and after variables instead?

Comment: Yes, I would look at both the mean of the differences and the means before the differencing. It is a good way to make sure that something doesn't look off and you get a better sense of what is going on with the change.